# How did I set up this particle system?

Tags: particles, physics

Using Blender 2.93.

A while ago, I made a paper mache dancer inspired by the Major Lazer Light it Up music video. I'm trying to refamiliarize myself with how I set this up and I can't figure it out how I referenced the bouncy mache particles.

[image]

It says rendered as path in the particle settings, but I don't see anywhere where I might have instanced the object into the particle system. The only way I see to instance the particle around the dancer is by rendering as object, but somehow I got it to work as path and it looks way better this way.

I even thought maybe it was something to do with an earlier Blender version and tried 2.83.

Can someone help me figure out HOW I figured out how to do this so many months ago?

Blend File
https://pasteall.org/blend/dab14583f83344789834725da3b55895

Answer (score 1):

[image]Figured it out. I didn't instance a plane over the object as particle system. I changed the hair shape of the particle system to look like a bunch of planes. Solution in the picture. Will only show in Cycles.

Comment: Do you want to add a screenshot to clarify your solution?